# Prove the norm convergence of self-adjoint operator in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces

I want to prove the following statement:

> Let $H$ be a positive self-adjoint operator, not necessarily bounded. For each real positive number $\lambda$, define $H_{\lambda} = \lambda (H+\lambda I)^{-1}$.
>
> Prove that each $H_{\lambda}$ is a bounded self-adjoint operator and that $H_{\lambda} \to H$ as $\lambda \to \infty$ strongly (i.e. $|| H_{\lambda} \varphi - H \varphi || \to 0$ when $\lambda \to \infty$ for every $\varphi \in D(H)$, where $D(H)$ is domain.

My intuition says that mentioned statement is correct, because of the following inequality (assuming $T$ bounded):
$|| (I + \lambda (T - \lambda I)^{-1} || \leq \frac{||T||}{|\lambda - ||T||}$

and when $\lambda \to 0$, $|| (I + \lambda (T - \lambda I)^{-1} || \to 0$ and so $||\lambda (T - \lambda I)^{-1}|| \to I$.

The main problem is that I don't really know how to prove this for every self-adjoint $H$ not necessarily bounded.

Thanks to for the readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $H$ is positive, then, for $\lambda > 0$,
$$
   \lambda\|x\|^2 \le ((H+\lambda I)x,x) \le \|(H+\lambda I)x\|\|x\|,\;\;\; x\in\mathcal{D}(H) \\
                      \lambda\|x\|\le \|(H+\lambda I)x\|,\;\; x\in\mathcal{D}(H) \\
                      \lambda\|(H+\lambda I)^{-1}y\|\le \|y\|,\;\; y \in H.
$$
So $\|\lambda (H+\lambda I)^{-1}\| \le 1$ for all $\lambda > 0$. For $x\in\mathcal{D}(H)$,
\begin{align}
     \|\lambda(H+\lambda I)^{-1}x-x\|&=\|\lambda(H+\lambda I)^{-1}-(H+\lambda I)^{-1}(H+\lambda I)x\| \\
   &=\|(H+\lambda I)^{-1}Hx\| \\
   &\le \frac{1}{\lambda}\|Hx\|\rightarrow 0 \mbox{ as } \lambda\rightarrow\infty.
\end{align}
Let $y$ be general. For any $x\in\mathcal{D}(H)$,
\begin{align}
    \|\lambda(H+\lambda I)^{-1}y-y\| &=\|\lambda(H+\lambda I)^{-1}(y-x)+\lambda(H+\lambda I)^{-1}x-x+(x-y)\| \\
   &\le \|y-x\|+\|\lambda(H+\lambda I)^{-1}x-x\|+\|x-y\|
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
       \limsup_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\|\lambda(H+\lambda I)^{-1}y-y\| \le 2\|y-x\|,\;\;\; x\in \mathcal{D}(H).
$$
Because the above holds for all $x\in\mathcal{D}(H)$, and because $\mathcal{D}(H)$ is dense in the underlying space, then the following holds for all $y$:
$$
         \lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\lambda (H+\lambda I)^{-1}y=y.
$$
That gives an approximation to $H$ where, for $x\in\mathcal{D}(H)$,
$$
    Hx= \lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\lambda (H+\lambda I)^{-1}Hx
  = \lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\lambda\left\{ x-\lambda(H+\lambda I)^{-1}x\right\}
$$
The operator $H_{\lambda}=\lambda\{ I-\lambda(H+\lambda I)^{-1} \}$ is symmetric and bounded, which makes it selfadjoint.

Comment: Your the best !!! Thank you so muchhh!!
I'm going to proceed this in my head now...

Comment: Hey. Now i'm tring to solve a little variation of previous problem in this link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016168/prove-the-norm-convergence-of-self-adjoint-operator-in-hilbert-space-variation?noredirect=1&__=2120014683#comment4139194_2016168. I added an H in H lambda and tried to use the same technic to solve it. Can you give me your opinion please?