# Prove the norm convergence of self-adjoint operator in Hilbert space (Variation)

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces

This is a little variation of following question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1998643/edit

I'd like to prove the following statement:

> Let $H$ be a positive self-adjoint operator, not necessarily bounded. For each real positive number $\lambda$, define $H_{\lambda} = \lambda H(H+\lambda I)^{-1}$.
>
> Prove that each $H_{\lambda}$ is a bounded self-adjoint operator and that $H_{\lambda} \to H$ as $\lambda \to \infty$ strongly (i.e. $|| H_{\lambda} \varphi - H \varphi || \to 0$ when $\lambda \to \infty$ for every $\varphi \in D(H)$, where $D(H)$ is domain.

I tried to use same procedure of this link https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1998643/edit, but I couldn't do it, taking this modification $H_{\lambda} = \lambda H(H+\lambda I)^{-1}$.

Someone can help me please?

Any idea?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1998643/prove-the-norm-convergence-of-self-adjoint-operator-in-hilbert-space/1999574#1999574

Comment: Well... TriaAndError thank you for your comment. But now im tring to solve a little v~riation of that problem, amd everything has changed with that variation...

Comment: For $x\in\mathcal{D}(H)$, $\lambda H(H+\lambda I)^{-1}x=\lambda(H+\lambda I)^{-1}Hx\rightarrow Hx$ as $\lambda\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I did it !